# Show two div elements after each other using timer and JS/Promise

Tags: javascript, timer, promise

**Problem:**

I have two divs that I wish to show after each other with each having a 15 second delay.

**HTML/CSS:**

```
<style>
  .js-success,
  .js-danger {
    display: none;
  }
</style>

<h2 class="js-success">
  <span class="badge badge-success"><i class="fas fa-clock"></i></span>
</h2>
<h2 class="js-danger">
  <span class="badge badge-danger"><i class="fas fa-clock"></i></span>
</h2>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
/**
 * Shows and hides steps
 */

const hasClass = (node, className) => node.className.indexOf(className) > -1;

const nodeVisible = (node, show = true) => {
  const showCssClass = "d-block";
  if (show) {
    if (!hasClass(node, showCssClass)) {
      node.classList.add(showCssClass);
    }
  } else {
    node.classList.remove(showCssClass);
  }
};

/**
 * Timer
 */

const timer = (count) => new Promise(resolve => {
  let counter = setInterval(() => {
    count = count - 1;
    if (count < 0) {
      clearInterval(counter);
      resolve();
      return;
    }
  }, count);
});

/**
 * Call timer
 */

timer(15)
  .then(() => {
      const success = node.querySelector(".js-success");
      nodeVisible(success); 
  });
```

`nodeVisible` works without any issues, but for some reason the success badge is visible directly when the page loads despite having `display: none`.

Desired outcome:

I wish that `.js-success` would be displayed after 15 seconds, then it shall be replaced by `.js-danger` after another 15 seconds.

Comment: Why `.classList.add()`/`.classList.remove()` but `.className.indexOf()` instead of `.classList.contains()`?

Comment: @Andreas Good addition, thanks. Any ideas about the main issue?

Comment: Check how `setInterval` and `setTimeout` work. Especially what every parameter represents - especially the second one.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks, very appreciated.